# What is the purpose of a semicolon after an opening brace

Tags: php, for-loop

I am having trouble finding out what the purpose of this semicolon is at `for (;` . My searches online have only brought irrelevant results. Can someone explain this please?

```
for (; $this->foo <=10; $this->foo++) {}
```

Comment: It means the first clause is empty - there are no initialisations. Wait until you see `for(;;)`

Comment: It means that you don't want to initialize your variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This basically skips the initializing of the iterator variable. Normally you'd type something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $this->foo <= 10; $i++) {}
```

in your example however your object which is accessed by the `$this` simply accumulates the foo by 1;

Answer (score 2):

The first expression in a for loop is being executed at the beginnig of the loop, usually for initializing a variable.

In this for loop the expression is empty, so nothing is going to happen at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`For` loop can work fine with `for(;;)` which is known as infinite loop.
It doesn't have any initialization part, no conditional checks and no post operation.

```
for(initialization, condition check, increment/decrement)
```

These are the 3 parts of `for` loop